# Response from query couldn't map to pojo class spring boot

Tags: mysql, sql, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Every response from query should be mapped to a poja class.

I have written a native query

```
@Query(value="SELECT new QuestionJsonTotalAnswer(q.question) FROM mydb.question q", nativeQuery=true)
List<QuestionJsonTotalAnswer> showAnswersOfQuestions();
```

**Converter class**

```
public class QuestionJsonTotalAnswer {
    String question;
    // constructors, getters and setters
}
```

But the error is:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '(q.question) FROM mydb.question q' at line 1

In application.properties

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

Note : Its working fine without pojo class when I get the response through `List<Object>`. But I need to get through pojo class to avoid nested arrays.

Comment: try to `nativeQuery = false` and put full package name of `QuestionJsonTotalAnswer` on query

Comment: @MortezaJalambadani he uses native query for some reasons and he mentioned it there

Answer (score 2):

You need to use projection like this.

```
@Query(value="SELECT q.question FROM mydb.question q", nativeQuery=true)
List<QuestionJsonTotalAnswer> showAnswersOfQuestions();

public interface QuestionJsonTotalAnswer {
    String getQuestion();
}
```